# Strange number error in HLSL

Tags: c#, hlsl, slimdx

I have a very-very strange problem with my project. I tried to send an index number with my vertices, and use this number in the HLSL shader.

But, when I set this number to a value, like, 1, the shader get a very wide spectrum from that number - going down to negative value, between 0-1 and above 1. Even when I give in nonsense numbers, like 10000

(I use C# with SlimDX, and this is made with pixel shader 2.0 and I tried 3.0 as well.)

```
        int c = 0;

        int testValue = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < tris.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[c].Position = tris[i].p0;
            vertices[c].Normal = tris[i].normal;
            vertices[c].Index = testValue;
            vertices[c++].Color = Color.LightBlue.ToArgb();

            vertices[c].Position = tris[i].p1;
            vertices[c].Normal = tris[i].normal;
            vertices[c].Index = testValue;
            vertices[c++].Color = Color.LightBlue.ToArgb();

            vertices[c].Position = tris[i].p2;
            vertices[c].Normal = tris[i].normal;
            vertices[c].Index = testValue;
            vertices[c++].Color = Color.LightBlue.ToArgb();
        }
```

This is how I create my vertices. Everything works as they should work, except the Index value. I get the colors right, I get the normals right, I get the position right.

Here is the HLSL code:

```
VertexToPixel IndexedRenderedVS( float4 inPos : POSITION, float4 inColor : COLOR0, float3 inNormal : NORMAL, int inIndex : TEXCOORD0)
{
VertexToPixel Output = (VertexToPixel)0;

float4x4 xWorldViewProjection = mul(xWorld, xViewProjection);

Output.Position = mul(inPos, xWorldViewProjection);

if (inIndex < 0)
    Output.Color = float4(1, 0, 0, 1);

 if (inIndex > 0 && inIndex < 1)
     Output.Color = float4(0, 1, 0, 1);

 if (inIndex > 1)
     Output.Color = float4(0, 0, 1, 1);

 //Output.Color = inColor;

return Output;    
}

 PixelToFrame IndexedRenderedPS(VertexToPixel PSIN)

 {
 PixelToFrame Output = (PixelToFrame)0;

 Output.Color = PSIN.Color;

 return Output;
 }
```

And finally, my VertexFormat struct:

```
    internal Vector3 Position;
    internal int Color;
    internal Vector3 Normal;
    internal int Index;

    internal static VertexElement[] VertexElements = new VertexElement[]
    {
        new VertexElement(0, 0, DeclarationType.Float3, DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.Position, 0),
        new VertexElement(0, sizeof(float) * 3, DeclarationType.Color, DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.Color, 0),
        new VertexElement(0, sizeof(float) * 7, DeclarationType.Float3, DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.Normal, 0),
        new VertexElement(0, sizeof(float) * 10, DeclarationType.Float1, DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),
        VertexElement.VertexDeclarationEnd
    };

    internal static VertexFormat Format
    {
        get { return VertexFormat.Position | VertexFormat.Diffuse | VertexFormat.Normal | VertexFormat.Texture1; }
    }
```

With this code, and an insane index value (10000 - I get a same picture, no matter what values I give in, 0, 1, or even when I put negative numbers in. It just dont care what I give in).

I get this picture:
[image: Asteroid]

Anybody have any idea where I make a mistake? I simply cant find where I misplaced some value. Tried a huge number of vertex declaration, changed everything in inside the shader - and now I offically ran out from ideas.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: You should provide your drawing code, and how you create your inputlayout

Comment: Are you using DX9 or higher? If higher maybe its a padding issue (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782061/d3d10-constant-buffer-not-working/14784040#14784040). There is a little error in your vertexdeclaration, there youre index is typed as float1 in your shader as int.

Answer (score 1):

In DirectX, texture coordinates are always floats, usually a float2, but sometimes a float3 or float4 (you can specify a float1, but if you do you'll actually get a float2 in the assembly and the runtime will throw away the second channel). You're typing it on the CPU side as an int, and then in the vertex description as a float1, and finally in the shader as an int. I would recommend typing all of these as float2 to start.